# Where can i ckeck all the attribute fields of salesforce objects?

Tags: fields, attribute

I'm a new developer in salesforce, and just realize that there are some "attribute fields" (i don't know if that's the correct name) but i cant figure it out where are those field "set"/"declare".

Fields like "isWon" or "isClosed" in the Opportunity Object, i just cant find where are declared ( i cant see those fields in the Opportunity - "Fields & Relationship section, BUT i can see those fields/attributes in the formula settings for validation rules).

Example: The field/attribute "Closed (API Name isClosed)"
[image]

BUT is not in the Fields & Relationship section :( 
[image]

Comment: Maybe, by Ant or other Migration Tool....

Comment: All fields are listed in the SOAP Api documentation. Here's the one related to the Opportunity object: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.218.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_opportunity.htm. You can also check the other objects thanks to the navigation menu on the left.

Comment: @[Martin Lezer] You should write that as an answer, maybe expanding slightly to say that their ability to be directly set is also included in that reference.

Comment: oh!  perfect! yes @MartinLezer thats exactly what i was looking for!; and yes if you can write that as an answer so i can select it! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All fields are listed in the SOAP Api documentation. Here's the one related to the Opportunity sObject: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.218.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_opportunity.htm.

Each operation available on the field is noted in "Properties".

In your case, you can see that the `IsClosed` and `IsWon` fields can't be updated because the operations listed are: `Defaulted on create, Filter, Group, Sort`

Finally, You can also check the other objects thanks to the navigation menu on the left.

Answer (score 0):

The `IsClosed` and `IsWon` fields are available in reporting, process builders, workflow rules, validation Rules and formulas.

They cannot be accessed from fields and relationship section neither can be added to the page layout.

`IsClosed` field is marked as `true` if the `Opportunity` is in a `Stage` marked as `Closed/Lost` or `Closed/Won` Stage, else it is `false` 
Similarly, `IsWon` field is marked as `true` if the `Opportunity` is in a `Stage` marked as `Closed/Won` Stage, else it is `false`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i was looking for where can i look at for known all those fields that are not in fields and relationship but that can be used, it was state by MartinLezer at one comment.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Martin Lezer, he just give me where i can look at to find all those fields that cannot be accessed from "fields and relationship" section(SOAP API Documentation):
[SOAP API Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.218.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_opportunity.htm)